# OOP design: class inherit class that contains field of class that inherit another class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
public static class A {

    public void doA() {

    }

}

public static class B extends A {

    public void doB() {

    }

}

public static class AE {
    protected A field;

    public AE(A field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        field.doA();
    }

}

public static class BE extends AE {

    // wanna have B field;

    public BE(B field) {
        super(field);
    }

    public void doAnotherStuff() {
        field.doA();
        field.doB(); // error here
    }

}
```

What is the best solution for such design problem?
I see two options:
1) cast to B type field everytime when you need to call doB()

```
((B) field).doB();
```

2) save B as another field fo BE class, and call this field when you need doB() functionality:

```
protected B field2;

    public BE(B field) {
        super(field);
        field2 = field;
    }
```

Both solutions are obvious and isn't nice. In case 1) you lost performance on runtime casts, and cast field everytime looks like an error.
In case 2) we have two fields in class BE that contains pointers to exact same object B, differs only in type (field of class A and field2 of class B);
Is there any better solutions for this problem?

Comment: You could use generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public static class AE<T extends A> {
    protected T field;

    public AE(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        field.doA();
    }

}

public static class BE extends AE<B> {

    // wanna have B field;

    public BE(B field) {
        super(field);
    }

    public void doAnotherStuff() {
        field.doA();
        field.doB();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I need! Now I feel really stupid that don't figured it out by myself...

Answer (score 0):

As @Eran suggested  you can use generics or you can do something like this instead:

```
public static class AE {
    private A field;

    public AE(A field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public void doStuff() {
        field.doA();
    }

    protected A getField() {
        return field;
    }
}

public static class BE extends AE {

    public BE(B field) {
        super(field);
    }

    @Override
    protected B getField() {
        return (B) super.getField();
    }

    public void doAnotherStuff() {
        getField().doA();
        getField().doB(); // no error here
    }

}
```

Adding a protected getter and overriding it in sub class. This way you would need to cast the type just once.

Comment: this is basically the same code as the answer with generics, except you do the type checking at runtime, not compile-time. why bother?